# I want to perform calculation on a variable in CSS. Is there a way to do this WHITHOUT preprocessors or JavaScript? [ACCEPTED]

Tags: css, var, calc

I want to do something like this.
I want to make use of a single varible for multiple elements that have different values for the same property.

like this
v v v

```
:root {
  --brd_rad: 2rem;
}

#something {
  border-radius: var(--brd_rad);
}

#other-thing {
  border-radius: calc(var(--brd_rad) + 1);  /*obviously this doesn't work */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a unit in the value you're adding in the `calc`. Is it meant to be `1px` or `1rem` or `1%`?

```css
:root {
  --brd_rad: 2rem;
}

#something {
  border-radius: var(--brd_rad);
  border:1px solid blue;
  height:100px;
}

#other-thing {
  border:1px solid red;
  height:100px;
  border-radius: calc(var(--brd_rad) + 1rem); 
}
```

```html
<div id="other-thing"></div>
<div id="something"></div>
```

Comment: OMG! such a silly mistake. Thank you.